# OAuth2 Server to Server Expiring Token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, microservices, pingfederate

We are using OAuth2 to validate our server to server interactions.  The Grant Type is Client Credentials.

If I have Service1  running on ServerA all is well - when the token is about to expire it just gets another one.

But if I scale up Service1 to run on 2 servers using the same CLIENT_ID: ServerA requests a token, then ServerB requests a token.  The second request for a token invalidates the 1st token. A loop begins...

If the AuthServer is setup to  always return the SAME token to each Server, then I have the problem of how do I request a new token before the first one expires?

How can ServerA and ServerB reasonably share a token?

I can't be the first one to encounter this design challenge.  Anyone?